# How to declare return type of C++ template method to be that of static method in other class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to do the valid C++11 equivalent of the following (apparently) invalid code:

```
class StaticMethodClass {
public:
    static int staticMethod(int a) {return 0;}
};

#include <type_traits>

template<class T> class ClassTemplate {
public:
    decltype(T::staticMethod(int)) methodTemplate(int a);
};

template<class T>
decltype(T::staticMethod(int)) ClassTemplate<T>::methodTemplate(int a) {
    return T::staticMethod(a);
}

template class ClassTemplate<StaticMethodClass>;
```

I get the following errors from my compiler:

```
/tmp$ g++ -std=c++11 -c a.cpp
a.cpp:14:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 decltype(T::staticMethod(int)) ClassTemplate<T>::methodTemplate(int a) {
                          ^
a.cpp:14:32: error: prototype for ‘decltype (T:: staticMethod(<expression error>)) ClassTemplate<T>::methodTemplate(int)’ does not match any in class ‘ClassTemplate<T>’
 decltype(T::staticMethod(int)) ClassTemplate<T>::methodTemplate(int a) {
                                ^
a.cpp:10:36: error: candidate is: int ClassTemplate<T>::methodTemplate(int)
     decltype(T::staticMethod(int)) methodTemplate(int a);
                                    ^
/tmp$ g++ -dumpversion
4.8.3
```

Is what I want to do possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `std::result_of` works this way. It's defined as `result_of<F(ArgTypes...)>` (see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)). That `F` argument should be a *type*. When you write `T::staticMethod` you are giving `result_of` the *function*, not the *type*.

> F must be a callable type, reference to function, or reference to callable type. Invoking F with ArgTypes... must be a well-formed expression.

So what you want is to give `result_of` the type of the reference to that function. A pointer to that function is given by `&T::staticMethod`, and its type by `decltype(&T::staticMethod)`. This code works.

```
typename std::result_of<decltype(&T::staticMethod)(int)>::type methodTemplate(int i) {
    return T::staticMethod(i);
}
```

Also note `typename` as pointed out by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031257/1749822).

Answer (score 2):

[`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) should make the trick:

```
auto methodTemplate(int i) -> decltype(T::staticMethod(i)) {
    return T::staticMethod(i);
}
```

in C++14 you could skip `decltype`:

```
auto methodTemplate(int i) {
    return T::staticMethod(i);
}
```

Comment: @SteveEmmerson Try with `decltype`.

Answer (score 0):

This works (http://ideone.com/6pczX3):

```
decltype(T::staticMethod(int)) methodTemplate(int i) {
    return T::staticMethod(i);
}
```

At first I thought you probably just need to add `typename` appropriately, but that didn't work.

Comment: That worked for the initial code, where `methodTemplate()` was implemented in the class declaration. Moving the implementation outside the class, however, results in the same problem. See the revised code.

Answer (score 0):

```
decltype(T::staticMethod(int)) methodTemplate(int a);
```

should be

```
decltype(T::staticMethod(0)) methodTemplate(int a);
```

or

```
decltype(T::staticMethod(std::declval<int>())) methodTemplate(int a);
```

(And same for definition).

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e949e33868b049a)